# Clear Android Context at sign out

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using Context in order to store user information, so that when she starts the app it will automatically retrieve the username from the context like this:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
String userId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_USER_ID, "");
```

I want to avoid retrieving this data when the user has clicked on SIGN OUT. How can I delete this context, or how can I manage this situation otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [SharedPreferences.remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29) to remove `PROPERTY_USER_ID` on `SIGN OUT` button click:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.remove(String.valueOf(PROPERTY_USER_ID));
editor.commit();
```